# free space characters after saving my delphi records in stream or file

Tags: delphi, stream, compression, indy, records

i have an application (server/client) with delphi and indy . my client sending some records to server . i want to compress my whole records before sending to server(i want compress whole records together , not compress field by field ) , well my idea was save my records to a stream then send my stream to server and in server side read my stream then decompress stream . all of my records are strings . my problem is when i save my records in stream or a file , after saving there are many free spaces between record fields , for example in field name : 'david.....................'(after david there are many spaces till next field).well i dont want these free spaces couse they made my stream size larger even if i have not data in some of fields. is there any solution to send records without this space characters ?

thanks
best regard 
ray petriut

a part of my code is :

```
type
Tmyrecord = record
IPStr: string[15];
pcname:string[15];
os:string[100];
dateinstall:string[15];
cpu:string[100];
mainboard:string[100];
vga:string[100];
hdd:string[100];
hddcapa:string[15];
nt:string[100];
macaddress:string[20];
end;



procedure TForm27.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
MIRec: Tmyrecord;
msRecInfo: TMemoryStream;

begin
client.Host:=edit1.Text;
client.connect();
if client.Connected=true then
begin

mirec.os:=edit2.text;
mirec.dateinstall:=edit3.text;
mirec.pcname:=edit4.text;
mirec.cpu:=edit5.text;
mirec.mainboard:=edit6.text;
mirec.vga:=edit7.text;
mirec.hdd:=edit10.text;
mirec.hddcapa:=edit9.text;
mirec.nt:=edit8.text;
mirec.macaddress:=edit11.text;
mirec.ipstr:=edit12.text;

msRecInfo := TMemoryStream.Create;
try
 msRecInfo.Write(MIRec, SizeOf(MIRec));
 Client.IOHandler.Write(msRecInfo, 0, True);
 finally
  msRecInfo.Free;
     end;



   client.disconnect;
        end
    else showmessage('can not connect to server ');

    end;
```

Comment: why dont you try to write the record as a string? you can use a seperator for each field. Another way is trying to write data to a file, compress the file and send it as binary.

Comment: Why did you decide to use fixed length strings, that don't support Unicode?

Comment: You said you were going to compress your data. I don't see where you've done that. Compressing will make the extra spaces largely irrelevant.

Comment: my data compressor is in another procedure i have not problem with compression i have 2 way for compression, compress records as a string file or a stream. when i write data in a file there are many free spaces because of fixed lenght records.... well my data have not problem with unicode , is there another way to write records in (not) fixed length strings and get them in server side without any problem ? what ways for not fixed records what solution i can use  ?  if i compress data field by field without write to stream i will be bigger size couse my separated strings are shorts ..thanks

Comment: You might not have a problem with Unicode, but you'd better hope that nobody wants to store data that's not ANSI. As Rob says, if you are compressing then the compression will deal with the trailing spaces. If the trailing data really are spaces and not uninitialised noise. If it were me I'd stop using 20 year deprecated short strings, I'd use actual strings, and I'd serialize to, e.g. JSON, binary JSON if size really matters.

Comment: thanks , what about using tsringlist to save a group of strings or wide strings then send them to tstreamstring with indy ? or better use of dynamic array record ? thanks for reply

Comment: Why do you need a string list? A record is good. It's the short strings that are the problem.

Comment: well i think i could use a group of strings and separated them with an index character instead of fixed records so i don't need to store a size for my strings records and when i save them in a stream they will not use free space characters if some fields were less than stored in fixed size, for example if i store string[30] for store name in a record,and then the name was david it will not save 25 free space character in this way if i save strings with a separator index . .. if there are a good way instead of this pleas tell me . .. thanks for your fast reply

Comment: I don't think there's much point continuing this discussion. You seem set on using short strings. If that is so then I can't help.

Comment: thank you david , what is your idea then ? the short strings is not that important for me,,,, tell me your idea or an example link of your solution i will try it . thanks

Comment: I already did so in comments above. Short strings should be important to you. Specifically that they were deprecated 20 years ago and should never be used. That should mean something. Unless you use @david I don't get notified of comments.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, well i have not problem with unicode and actual strings ,. you said you are using actual strings and serialize to, e.g. JSON, binary JSON , but i never used this method before , i want know if you have some example links to use this method and use actual string and unicode in records please tell me , thanks

Comment: There are a gazillion examples of this available if you search. You say you don't have problems with Unicode. That's fine if you only want to use ASCII characters, and all your users are happy with that. I guess you'd better hope that you only deal with people who speak English. Deciding ahead of time how long your strings should be seems to be a problem to me. Why would you wish to constrain yourself in that way? Anyway, if you really think that fixed length short strings are the answer, then as I said, there is nothing I can offer you.